# making 2 box plots from the same data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to make a 2 box plots with y being weight and x being the before and after. so two different boxplot will be displayed at the same time.

```
`rats_before = data.frame(
  rat_num = paste0(rep("rat number",200),1:200),
  weight = rweibull(200,shape= 10,scale = 20))

rats_after = data.frame(
  rat_num = paste0(rep("rat number",200),1:200),
  weight = rweibull(200,shape= 9,scale = 21))

rats = merge(rats_before,rats_after, by = c("rat_num"))`
```

i know the next part is not even close but it will give you a idea of what im trying to do.

```
rat_boxplot = qplot(y = weight, x = (rats_after, rats_before), geom = "boxplot", data = rats)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, if you want to do this in base R -

```
rats_before = data.frame(
  rat_num = paste0(rep("rat number",200),1:200),
  weight = rweibull(200,shape= 10,scale = 20))

rats_after = data.frame(
  rat_num = paste0(rep("rat number",200),1:200),
  weight = rweibull(200,shape= 9,scale = 21))

rats <- rbind(rats_before, rats_after)
rats$type <- c(rep("before", nrow(rats_before)), rep("after", nrow(rats_after))) 
rats$type <- factor(rats$type)
rats$type <- relevel(rats$type, ref = 2)

boxplot(weight ~ type, data = rats)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to each df ans use`rbind` which will bind the rows of the two df instead of `merge` you can use. Then you simply have to use the aes of a ggplot.

```
rats_before$condition = "before"
rats_after$condition = "after"
rats = rbind(rats_before,rats_after)
ggplot(rats)+geom_boxplot(aes(condition,weight))
```

Hope I understood your question.

Tom